# Display the sum of the product of two columns in crystal reports?

Tags: c#, dataset, formula, crystal-reports-2010

I have a crystal report connected to a dataset that contains three linked tables in c#.

**Employee**
EmpID*
EmpName
...Blah blah
**Leave**
LeaveNo*
EmpID
DateTaken
Days
Rate
**Slip**
SlipNo
EmpID
Month-Year

Now I want to display the EmpID, EmpName, LeaveDeduction for a specific month where
LeaveDeduction=Days * Rate for a specifc EmpID
(i). What do I use so I could display the LeaveDeduction field ?
(ii). How do I perform this calculation for a specific month ? (as the Leave table will store records for all the months but I want to display of only one month)

I am new to crystalreports and am running on only one tutorial and alot of try and error so please explain your answer more than you would do normally.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "formula fields" provided by crystal report to do some calculation. In field explore tab you can find formula fields. In formula field you can type the formula by giving the column name.